# Hive - explode and aggregate count?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hierarchy, explode

I have a hive table that stores a drive's path to the leaf node, and how many files it has. And want to build a new hive table that can look up how many files exists under any folder depth. Can I get some tips on how to achieve this?

My Input table is:

```
>select * from default.file_file
path file_count
/teamA/projectA/ 3
/teamA/projectB/ 2
```

I'm trying to build the output table so that it can look like:

```
>select * from default.output_table
path file_count
/ 5
/teamA/ 5
/teamA/projectA/ 3
/teamA/projectB/ 2
```

So Far I tried the lateral_view + explode method, but that doesn't allow me to keep track of the directory hierarchy (each `/` is stored in separate rows).

Comment: Seems you're querying Hive and not eg Spark, Trino or Presto. Removing unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can split path, then use running collect_set analytic function + concat_ws to build path again. After this aggregate file_count group by path:

Demo:

```
SELECT stack (2,
'/teamA/projectA/', 3,
'/teamA/projectB/', 2
) AS  (path, file_count)
)
 
select path, sum(file_count) file_count
from
(
select  t.file_count, 
        concat(concat_ws('/',collect_set(s.node) over(partition by t.path order by level))
               , '/'
              ) path
  from Table1 t
       --remove trailing /, split and explode 
       lateral view posexplode(split(regexp_replace(t.path,'/$',''),'/')) s as level, node
)s
group by path;
```

Result:

```
path                file_count
/                   5
/teamA/             5
/teamA/projectA/    3
/teamA/projectB/    2
```